# Taking similar consecutive rows and appending them into one longer row with AWK

Tags: awk

I've got a big 7-column text file with sorted rows like this:

```
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00884 C C 14   1.00         u
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00884 C C 26   0.76         p
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00884 C C 33   0.89         f
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00885 G G 14   1.00         u
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00885 A A 30   0.84         f
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00886 T T 31   0.81         f
```

What I'm needing to do is, if the first two columns are the same in consecutive rows, append the rest of the columns to the first row. There can be 1, 2, or 3 "similar" rows, and I need placeholders to keep columns intact if less than 3. So the above would look like this:

```
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00884 C C 14   1.00 u C C 26 0.76 p C C 33   0.89 f
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00885 G G 14   1.00 u -  -  -  ------------     G G 33   0.89 f
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00886 T T 31   0.81 f - -  -  ----        - -   -  ------ -  -   --   -----   -   -
```

I've tried many approaches with AWK but can't quite get it. How might this be done?

Comment: Post some of the code you have tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: It's not immediately clear how the order in which the fields are displayed is determined, nor the rule for "placeholders". Can you try to explain it a bit?

Comment: I can't understand how you are placing the placeholders. And where does `G G 33   0.89 f` come from in the second line of the output.

Comment: And where did "A A 30" go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about how you get your second row but this might match at least how I understand the goal:

```
awk '
{
  head=$1 " " $2
  tail=$3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " "$7
  if(previous!=head) {
    if(previous!="") printf("%s %s %s %s\n",previous,p[1],p[2],p[3])
    previous=head
    i=1
    p[i]=tail
    p[2]=p[3]="- - - -"
  } else {
    i=i+1
    p[i]=tail
  }
}
END { printf("%s %s %s %s\n",previous,p[1],p[2],p[3]) }'
```

Output:

```
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00884 C C 14 1.00 u C C 26 0.76 p C C 33 0.89 f
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00885 G G 14 1.00 u A A 30 0.84 f - - - -
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00886 T T 31 0.81 f - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! I'm sorry it took me so long to work out my problem, but this solution with a bit of adaptation worked great for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, better late than never !

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:
(Edit: I didn't notice you needed placeholders. I'll look into it....)

```
awk '
  $1 == last1 && $2 == last2 {
    printf " %s %s %s %s %s",$3,$4,$5,$6,$7;
    last1 = $1; last2 = $2;
    next;
  }
  {
    $1 = $1;  # normalize spacing
    printf "%s%s", NR==1?"":"\n", $0;
    last1 = $1; last2 = $2;
  }
  END { print ""; }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { maxRecs = 3 }
function prta(  i, dflt) {
    dflt = a[1]
    gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"-",dflt)
    printf "%s ", key
    for (i=1; i<=maxRecs; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", (i in a ? a[i] : dflt), (i<maxRecs ? OFS : ORS)
        delete a[i]
    }
    numRecs = 0
}
{ key = $1 FS $2 }
prev && (key != prev) { prta() }
{
    $1 = $1
    sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"")
    a[++numRecs] = $0
    prev = key
}
END { prta() }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00885 C C 14 1.00 u C C 26 0.76 p C C 33 0.89 f
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00886 G G 14 1.00 u A A 30 0.84 f - - - - -
gi|352964122|gb|JH286168.1| 00886 T T 31 0.81 f - - - - - - - - - -
```